# how to plot a histogram with a certain column(english_score) for a certain row of a column(group a) and set the number of bins to 20

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, histogram

I have a data set which I had to turned into a data frame. these data frame has 5 columns(  sex, group, course, english score, final_score) the column group has 5 unique groups(group a, group b....group e). What I need is to plot a histogram over english_score for group a and set the number of bins to 20.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: df.hist(column=[["english_score", "group"== "group a"]])